# If conditions are met define variable as _____

Tags: python, boolean

I'm trying to use some Boolean logic to define a variable.

```
if BestX!=1 or starcount!=1:
  x=cat

if BestX==1 or starcount==1:
  x=dog
```

where BestX and starcount are both lists. Basically if there are more than 1 items in the either list I don't want to define the variable `x` as 'cat'. If however there is only 1 item in both lists (at the same time), `x` should be defined as 'dog'.

As my logic stands currently if I have 1 item in starcount, but numerous items in BestX it is being defined as 'cat'...not what I want. How do I compose it so that if either of these are larger than 1 x will be defined as 'dog'.

(Sorry for the abstractness)

Comment: You seem to be comparing the list to 1 instead of the list's length.

Comment: Your question seems to have contradictory requirements, my answer has a solution for both.

Comment: Please clarify you logic.  Thank you.

Comment: Both lists must have 1 item in them for the variable to be defined as dog. If they *both* don't...x is defined as cat. Clear enough?

Comment: @Matt: No, that tells us what happens if both have 1, or if both don't have 1… it doesn't tell us what happens if one has 1 and the other has 2.

Comment: Oh, I see the hang up. Okay, unless they both have 1 item each they will be defined as 'cat'. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: @Matt Check out my latest answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you meant that you want `x=dog` if **either** of the lists have *at least one* element, do this

```
x=cat
if len(BestX) > 0 or (starcount) > 0:
  x=dog
```

Your question seems to state contradictory requirements.  You initially ask for `x=dog` if **both** of the lists have *exactly one* element, that would be achieved like this

```
x=cat
if len(BestX) == 1 and (starcount) == 1:
  x=dog
```

Upon clarification, the **second** solution seems to have solved OP's question

Answer (score 4):

You could do succinctly with python's version of the ternary operator:

```
x = dog if len(BestX) == 1 and len(starcount) == 1 else cat
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the problem, what you actually want is:

```
if len(BestX) != 1 or len(starcount) != 1:
    x=cat
else:
    x=dog
```

The only major problem with your code is that you're comparing `BestX` itself to `1`, not its length, and a list is never going to be equal to `1`.

---

Meanwhile, your two conditions don't cover the entire space. If one of the values is 1, and the other is not, *neither* condition will be true, which I don't think is what you want.

But I don't know what you actually *do* want, because your question is contradictory. I'll take your English and translate it into code, and hopefully that will be enough to get you going:

> if there are more than 1 items in the either list I don't want to define the variable x as 'cat'.

… presumably meaning you *do* want to define it as `dog`? Here's what that looks like:

```
if len(BestX) > 1 or len(starcount) > 1:
    x=dog
```

> If however there is only 1 item in both lists (at the same time), x should be defined as 'dog'.

… which I think is supposed to be the complement of the other case, in which case it's just:

```
else:
    x=dog
```

… or maybe you want to know if there's a total of 1 item in the two lists together?

```
elif len(BestX) + len(starcount) == 1:
    x=dog
```

… meaning that in other cases (e.g., there's exactly 1 in each list, or 0 in each) you end up with `x` undefined?

Also note that your description sets `x` to `dog` in both cases (or at least "not to cat" in one case and "to dog" in the other), which seems like of silly.

---

You may be wondering why Python allows you to compare a list to 1 at all, when the comparison is meaningless. Well, Python usually allows you to ask whether two items of completely unrelated types are equal, and just always answers that they're not. If you try using `>` instead of `!=`, you'll get a `TypeError` (in Python3—in Python 2, you used to get a consistent, but arbitrary and meaningless, answer).

Comment: Yeah, that problem of one list being 1 and the other not is my real problem. I think it was mentioned in my post. I have no idea how to get around this.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I compose it so that if either of these are larger than 1 x
>   will be defined as 'dog'.

Remember to handle the empty list case.

```
#if either list has more than one item
if len(BestX) > 1 or len(starcount) > 1:
    x=cat
#if both lists have only 1 item each
elif len(BestX) == 1 and len(starCount) == 1:
    x=dog
else:
    #do something if your case is 0 or negative!
    x=cat
```

This is very important in case you are not using len() in the conditions but much before than the checks. You may land up with a negative length if you are performing some calculations related to length.

EDIT:

> Oh, I see the hang up. Okay, unless they both have 1 item each they
>   will be defined as 'cat'. Hope that clears it up.

After clarification, here is a simple way to do what you want:

```
#if both lists have exactly 1 item each
if len(BestX) == 1 and len(starCount) == 1:
    x=dog
#all other cases
else:
    x=cat
```

An even simpler solution:

```
#default x as cat
x=cat
#change x if both lists have exactly 1 item each
if len(BestX) == 1 and len(starCount) == 1:
    x=dog
```